# javascript casting a string of regex into a type object

Tags: javascript

I have a box where the user inputs a regex, and in Javascript I take that value and have another string tested with it like so: (this is an abstraction of my real issue)

```
var regex = $('input').val();
regex.test('some string');
```

The only way I know to make sure to cast the `regex` to a safe `Object` type, is to use `eval()`.

Is that the best way of casting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RegExp constructor to create a pattern.

```
// The next line would escape special characters. Since you want to support
//    manually created RegExps, the next line is commented:
// regex = regexp.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1')

regex = new RegExp(regex);
//                      ^ Optionally, add the flags as a second argument, eg:
//regex=new RegExp(regex, 'i');   //Case-insensitive
```

**UPDATE**
You seem to misunderstand the usage of the `RegExp` constructor. The "*slash*-notation" is the "primitive" way to create a Regular expression. For comparsion, consider (`new` is optional):

```
"123"             ===    new String(123)
false             ===    new Boolean(1)
// Because a RegExp is an object, the strict compare `===` method evaluates to
//  false if the pattern is not the same object.
// Example:   /\d/ == /\d/   evaluates to false
//      To compare a regex pattern, use the `pattern` property
/[a-z]/i.pattern   ===    (new RegExp("[a-z]", "i")).pattern
```

The `RegExp` constructor takes two arguments, with the second one being optional:

1. *String* **Pattern** (without trailing and ending slashes)
2. *String (optional)* **Flags** A combination of:

   - `i` (ignore case)
   - `g` (global match)
   - `m` (multi-line (rarely used)).

Examples (`new` is optional):

```
Using constructor                 using slash-notation   # Notice:
RegExp('[0-9]');                /[0-9]/                  # no slashes at RegExp
RegExp('/path/to/file\.html$')  /path\/to\/file\.html$/  # the escaped \ 
RegExp('i\'m', 'i')             /i'm/i                   # \' vs ', 'i' vs /i
```

#### Implementing a "RegExp" form field using slash-notation

```
var regex = $('input').val();  //Example: '/^[0-9]+$/i'
// Using a RegEx to implement a Reg Exp, ironically..
regex = regex.match(/^\/([\S\s]+)\/([gim]{0,3})$/);
regex = regex || [, regex, ""];        // If the previous match is null,
                                     // treat the string as a slash-less RegEx
regex = new RegExp(regex[1], regex[2]);
regex.test('some string');
```

Comment: var r = '/^[0-9]+$/i'; 
r = new RegExp(r); 
r.test('5'); // return 'false'

Comment: @vsync Have a look at my updated answer to get a better understanding. You shouldn't use slashes at the RegEx. If you want to implement such, have a look at the code at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I want to understand why all this messy code to convert a slash-notation regex string to an object is better than using eval()

Comment: @vsync By using `eval`, the user can run arbitrary code which breaks your page. The method at the bottom of my answer is secure, and slightly faster than `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var regex = new RegExp( $('input').val() );
```

Comment: You have to remove the / and / and the flags from the string.